# Archive - Show Video from First Post

Tags: archives, videos

I am relatively new to developing in WordPress.  The way my posts are structured is the post title with a video underneath followed by text.  The videos supplied by my client are in JavaScript tags.  What I am looking to accomplish with the archive page is to display the video from the first post under the category header.

I have noticed that the JavaScript is wrapped in p tags when the post is published so I had tried to break the_content by p but did not get the results that I am looking for.

This is the code that I have in functions.php.

```
function the_post_video($post_id=NULL) {
   global $post;
   $target_post = $post;
   if($post_id !== NULL)
       $target_post = get_post($post_id);

   $matches = null;
   if(preg_match('/<script(.*?)\\/?>(<\\/script>)?/s', $post->content, $matches)) {
      return $matches[0];
   }
   return ''; // return empty if no iframe found.
}
```

Note: Currently the site is not live.

Any assistance is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a working solution to this. I wrapped the JavaScript in a DIV. All other content is automatically wrapped in paragraph tags. In archive.php, I have it pull the most recent post in the section where I want the video. In the CSS, I have set display:none to the paragraph tags. Thanks everyone!